# Rnnoise not working in PulseEffects

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I am using PulseEffects for mic noise reduction, and I have to install it from flathub because Rnnoise is not available in Ubuntu repos and noise reduction is grayed out in PulseEffect app available in the official repo. PulseEffects flatpak is taking a huge space and this is a problem if I want to make my own distro.

My question is: Is it possible to make PulseEffects noise removal working, like recompiling it, and how?

I am using Kubuntu 22.04.

Best regards.